# Can you do math on variables inside double curly braces in a html script?

Tags: javascript, html, django

this is a html file i currently have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{{unit.unit_class}}

<div id="stats"></div>

<script>
var str ="", i;
for(i = 1; i<=99; i++)
{
    str = str + "<p>level " + i + ": hp {{unit.hp_current}}</p>";
}
document.getElementById("stats").innerHTML = str;
</script>
</html>
```

that bit in the for loop {{unit.hp_current}} is a decimal number. It's value is currently set to 0.00, which it does display on my page. I was wondering if I was able to do arithmetic on this variable inside the double curly braces. I tried doing something like {{unit.hp_current + 3}} or {{unit.hp_current}} + 3 in order for the program to display 3.00 instead of 0.00, but it doesn't seem to work. Is this something I need to make a function for instead in my views.py?

Comment: If you are using `django` then you can do some thing like `{{ unit.hp_current|add:"3"}}`

Answer (score 0):

No, django template language does not support operations on variables. You will need to calculate values in-code, then pass them to the template. Another way is to use a function in a template, that would calculate the value you need:

> When the template engine encounters a variable, it evaluates that
>   variable and replaces it with the result.
>   ...
>
> If the resulting value is callable, it is called with no arguments.
>   The result of the call becomes the template value.
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/

Yet another option is to use filters:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/#filters

Answer (score 0):

The vairables are directly set into the HTML using the template engine , I think you should store it in some variable and than do some other arthematic operations,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<div id="stats"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

let template_value = "{{unit.unit_class}}";
let hp_current = parseFloat(template_value);
let str = '';

for(let i = 1; i<=99; i++)
{
    str = str + `<p>level ${i} hp ${hp_current}</p>`;
}
document.getElementById("stats").innerHTML = str;
</script>
</html>
```

you can put this kind of substitution into your JavaScript.
It is kind of the dynamic javascript , Here we have stored the value in a variable called **hp_current** , Now you can use this for arthematic , Even you should use the backticks in here to concatinate the variables . Try out the code up here if it can work for you !

Comment: did you mean ```let template_value = "{{unit.hp_current}}";``` instead of ```let template_value = "{{unit.unit_class}}";```? 
in my models, unit_class is a ForeignKey that references a different class, and hp_current is a DecimalField.

Comment: I mean If you are writing like this let template_value = "{{unit.hp_current}}"; it just treated as a string in javascript . If you replace that with some number than code will work from next line ,other wise the  hp_current will contain the NAN in this case . I would suggest add that {{unit.unit_class}} to any hidden div and and fetch the valued in javascript using document.getElementById('id').innerHTML and use that value as you like .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that replicates your JS purely using Django template tags

```
<div id="stats">
  {% with ''|center:99 as range %}
  {% for _ in range %}
    <p>level {{ forloop.counter }}: hp {{ unit.hp_current }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
  {% endwith %}
</div>
```

As mentioned by @madhusudhan you can perform addition using filters

```
{{ unit.hp_current|add:forloop.counter }}
```